# Unable to run the exe file in python

Tags: python, exe

I have created the `exe` file using `pyinstaller`. I have run `pyinstaller` from the scripts folder of the Python package folder. The `exe` file appeared in `build` folder.

However, when I am trying run the `exe` file, it blinks open the black screen with cursor pointed at the zero-th position and goes away.

"The code works just fine when run on Jupyter Notebook."

Have any of you faced the similar problem? Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe execute the file in command prompt you may get the error code . so you can debug the app.

Comment: sounds like your exe file is opening and immediately closing again. Have you checked what happens when you run the exe without python, maybe with cmd.

Comment: Are you by chance accessing your file system? Jupyter notebook and your exe-file most likely won't have the same working directory, so you have to take care handling paths properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rename your main python file from *.py to *.pyw .
I use the following batch script for the last 5 years:

```
set VS100COMNTOOLS=%VS140COMNTOOLS%


copy /Y LazAngebote_APP.pyw LazAngebote_APP.old
copy /Y LazAngebote_APP.py LazAngebote_APP.pyw
setlocal
set PATH=C:\Python34;%PATH%

pyinstaller -y -D --name LazAngebote --paths "C:\Windows\System32\downlevel" --windowed -i C:\path_to_icon\ICONS\AI-2.ico --clean --distpath="." -p "c:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4" LazAngebote_APP.pyw

pause
```

If it still don´t work, copy the *.exe to a cmd/terminal an see if any errors where shown.

Comment: Thank you so much Salabur... It is working for me now... But , it does not work on other's system. Any tips for that ?

Comment: try -F instead of -D

Comment: If it works, I would be pleased if you could accept my question, I´m kind of new here and need those points ;)